# Spring Boot circular reference is already handled in application.properties but seems ignored by Java Spring Boot executable jar file

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ubuntu, spring-security

So the case is I a created simple login employee management system by using Java Spring Boot (very basic so it enough to have login-logout and CRUD operation). I also tried to use Spring Security to secure the authentication.

This it the spec of my Java Spring Boot application:

- spring tool suite 4.18.0.RELEASE
- spring security 6
- using java 17
- built on top linux ubuntu 22.04
- application.properties is already located in resource folder by default in `SBTLEmpManSys/src/main/resources`

I will attach my java files related to the error, `application.properties`, & `pom.xml` later but this is what I already handle. I have put this code `spring.main.allow-circular-references=true` in my `application.properties` to handle this error and it actually works

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfiguration (field private org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity)
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]
└─────┘
```

Everything works well when I ran it inside Spring Tool Suite IDE.

But the problem occur after I packed my Java Spring Boot application into executable jar file. It seems like file `application.properties` is ignored.

The circular reference seems happen in `EmpServiceImpl.java` around this line of codes:

```
@Service
public class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepDAO;
    
    //public EmpServiceImpl(@Lazy EmployeeRepository empRepDAO) { //ANNOTATION '@Lazy' is ADDITION to AVOID CIRCULAR REFERENCE --> ANNOTATION NOT WORKING
    public EmpServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository empRepDAO) {
        super();
        this.empRepDAO = empRepDAO;
    }

...[AND_SO_ON]
```

The way I ran the jar file is by going into directory `target` via terminal and run it with `java -jar SBTLEmpManSys-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. This is a snippet of error I got when I ran my app.

```
Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder': Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'httpSecurity': Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

I wonder why the error message said this `Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?` because it should be handled already in `application.properties`

Does anyone can help? Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks guys ;)

This is my `SecurityConfiguration.java`

```
package com.kastamer.sbtl.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.kastamer.sbtl.service.EmpService;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public EmpService empService;
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers(
                "/registrasi",
                "/js**",
                "/css**",
                "/img**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin((form) -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
        .logout((logout) -> logout.invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true).logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll());
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This is my service file 'EmpServiceImpl.java':

```
package com.kastamer.sbtl.service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.kastamer.sbtl.model.EmpRole;
import com.kastamer.sbtl.model.Employee;
import com.kastamer.sbtl.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import com.kastamer.sbtl.web.dto.EmpRegistrationDTO;

@Service
public class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepDAO; //this is interface extend JpaRepository<Employee, Long>
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    //@Autowired //THIS is ADDITION to AVOID CIRCULAR REFERENCE --> ANNOTATION NOT WORKING
    //public EmpServiceImpl(@Lazy EmployeeRepository empRepDAO) { //ANNOTATION '@Lazy' is ADDITION to AVOID CIRCULAR REFERENCE --> ANNOTATION NOT WORKING
    public EmpServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository empRepDAO) {
        super();
        this.empRepDAO = empRepDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee pegawai = empRepDAO.findByEmail(username);
        
        if (pegawai == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Email atau kata sandi tidak cocok!");
        }
        
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(pegawai.getEmail(), pegawai.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthority(pegawai.getRoles())); //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee save(EmpRegistrationDTO empRegistrationDTO) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee karyawan = new Employee(
                empRegistrationDTO.getFullName(),
                empRegistrationDTO.getEmail(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(empRegistrationDTO.getPassword()),
                Arrays.asList(new EmpRole("ROLE_USER")));
        
        return empRepDAO.save(karyawan); //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void simpanPembaruanData(Employee employee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        employee.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(employee.getPassword()));
        
        this.empRepDAO.save(employee);
    }
    
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthority(Collection<EmpRole> roles) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getNamaRole())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    //PART POJOK KARYAWAN
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return empRepDAO.findAll(); //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Optional<Employee> optEmp = empRepDAO.findById(id);
        Employee empl = null;
        
        if (optEmp.isPresent()) {
            empl = optEmp.get();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Karyawan dengan emp_id '" + id + "' tidak bisa ditemukan");
        }
        
        return empl; //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployeeById(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.empRepDAO.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortAscOrDesc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Sort runut = sortAscOrDesc.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() : Sort.by(sortField).descending();
        
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, runut);
        
        return this.empRepDAO.findAll(pageable); //return null;
    }
}
```

This is my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB
spring.datasource.username=[POSTGRES_USERNAME]
spring.datasource.password=[POSTGRES_PASSWORD]
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Default user login and password for spring security web login page (if spring security is enabled)
#spring.security.user.name=spring
#spring.security.user.password=spring123 
#spring.security.user.roles=USER

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

Comment: Rather than allowing circular dependencies (which is not a great idea) you should instead instantiate any circular beans using the `@Lazy` annotation. This will instead inject a proxy which will not use the real bean until it's called at runtime. In this way  you can break the circular dependency chain and your application context will start up.

Comment: Can you help me identify where I should put `@Lazy`? I actually already suspice cause of this circular reference in `EmpServiceImpl.java` and put `@Lazy` on it but gave no effect (I have edit this question & put this 1 more file--it is a service implementation). I want to intervene `EmployeeRepository` but the problem is it is an `interface` so I don't know what to with it.

Comment: If you are using constructor initialization (which you should be, and if not you should change to constructor initialization), you should put it on the constructor parameter.

Comment: Also if you're using constructor initialization you don't need `@Autowired` on your member variable. I'm pretty sure that's why the `@Lazy` annotation isn't having any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I finally solve the circular reference after eliminate `extends WebSecurityConfiguration` from my codes in file `SecurityConfiguration.java`